# How can i fix my commenting system from creating multiple comments? - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The problem is in replying, each time i submit a reply it a new reply and **comment** is created.
Here's my comments controller

```
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      if params[:parent_id].present?
        @comment = Comment.find(params[:parent_id]).replies.new.(comment_params)
      elsif params[:parent_id].blank?
          @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
        @comment.user = current_user
      end

    if @comment.save
    flash[:success] = 'Your comment was successfully added!'
    redirect_to :back
    else
      render 'new'
    end

  end

  def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    if @comment.destroy
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :parent_id)
  end
end
```

and 
and in my _comment.html.erb

```
<%= render comment.replies if comment.replies.any? %>
            <%= form_for [comment.post, comment.replies.new] do |f| %>
               <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id, :value => comment.id %>
               <%= f.text_field :body %>
               <%= f.submit 'reply', name: 'reply' %>
            <% end %>
```

in my model

```
belongs_to :parent,  class_name: "Comment"
has_many   :replies, class_name: "Comment", foreign_key: :parent_id, dependent: :destroy
```

When the reply is submitted the a params[:parent_id] is passed. 
The problem
If-Else statement is not working, I need it to know if a comment or a reply is submitted.
If it did work I don't know how to get the comment I'm creating the reply in.
Hope everything is clear, thanks.

Comment: paste server logs for the request, i mean parameters here

Comment: Yeah, what he said. Your `params[:parent_id]` check looks to be wrong, based on your form. Check what your params hash actually contains in the server logs, it's probably nested within the object scoped to the form, not at the root of the params hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your form `parent_id` is coming under comment params, so it should be something like this

```
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  if params[:comment][:parent_id].present?
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:parent_id]).replies.new.(comment_params)
  elsif params[:comment][:parent_id].blank?
    @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
end
```

Hope it helps!